# XAMPP & PHP - file downloads instead of running

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to run a PHP script from my browser.  I have XAMPP installed.  Status shows that all the important stuff is activated, including PHP.  I have a directory under htdocs called test in which I have a very simple index.php file with the following contents:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If I go to: `localhost/test` I get a satisfactory result will all sorts on information in a nice table.  When I go to `localhost/my_other_dir` I see a list of two files, as follows:

```
52719c32376853836_20..>      2013-10-30 19:56    55M     
installer.php                2013-10-30 19:55   527K
```

I expect that if I click on the installer.php file it will run the script and do some cool stuff that involves the other file in the directory.  This was working a couple of hours ago and I'm not aware of anything that I changed, other than installing XCode Command Line Tools on my MacBook, which is running Mavericks.

When I click on installer.php, however, instead of running the script it just tries to download the file.  What gives?

---

My server status shows the following:

```
XAMPP Status

This page offers you on one view all information about what's running and working and what's not.

Component                       Status         Hint
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MySQL database                  ACTIVATED       
PHP                             ACTIVATED       
Perl                            ACTIVATED
Common Gateway Interface (CGI)  ACTIVATED       
Server Side Includes (SSI)      ACTIVATED       
PHP extension »OPcache«         DEACTIVATED    see FAQ  
PHP extension »OCI8/Oracle«     DEACTIVATED    see FAQ
```

Comment: check if your server status.

Comment: It could be that PHP is turned off for that directory so your server is simply feeding it to you like it would any other file it doesn't recognize.

Comment: How would I know if PHP is turned off for that directory?  How would I turn it on?